# Hosting Codeigniter site on GoDaddy with shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-hosting, shared-hosting

Directory structure (`public_html`)

```
public html
htpasswds
application
    .htacess
cgi-bin
system
user_guide
index.php
```

Configuration file looks like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/index.php/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

`.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

`route.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

Under `application->controllers` I have two PHP files, `welcome` and `about` with methods in them.

Below are the links I am generating, which are

```
<li><a href='./welcome'>Home</a>
<li><a href='./welcome/first'>first</a></li>    
<li><a href='./welcome/second'>second</a></li>
<li><a href='./third'>Third</a></li>
<li><a href='./fourth>Four</a></li>
<li><a href='./five'>Five</a></li>
<li><a href='./six'>Six</a></li>
```

If I manually type `http://www.example.com/index.php/welcome/second`, I can access the page.
But I don't know how to generate the links for the same, and how to get rid of `index.php` in the URL.

Comment: I also got the same problem with godaddy.Unfortunately they did not support me and I could not removed index.php at godaddy server.hope you will find solution.

Comment: `<li><a href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/first'>first</a></li>` will produce your link. btw you missed first li ending tag

Comment: Oh! Typo again, with li ending tag. Thanks for this info. Other wise I was using hard coded full url path in hyperlinks.

Comment: The end tag for the `li` element is optional in HTML, so unless this is **X**HTML, the `</li>` tag does little more than bloat your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use the Anchor function for generating links. See documentation [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

The htaccess should remove the index.php before the url, and you should change this line to:

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```